# How to update Camunda DMN table at runtime?

Tags: camunda

I have a DMN table created with a few rules and deployed to Camunda.

How do we update DMN tables programmatically at run-time and add a new rule when it is already deployed?

Answer (score 1):

When you change the dmn table but keep the decision-key, a deployment will create a new revision of the table.
So yes, you can update dmn tables at runtime.

You can do so by either using the REST or the java API.

The java api relies on the RepositoryService#createDeployment Builder. The concrete implementation depends on where your files are stored, and how you read them. [Here are some examples](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/engine/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/engine/test/api/repository/RepositoryServiceTest.java#L96-L129).

```
 Deployment deployment = repositoryService.createDeployment() 
      .addString(resourceName, instanceAsString)
      .deploy();
```

Comment: Hi Jan, do you have any reference implementation or code sample, which can be used for doing this using Java APIs. 
I was able to update DMN with new rules, but not able to deploy, because new DMN also has same ID.

Comment: Hi Jan, deployment looks good as per the code suggested by you, I could see the latest DMN table on Cockpit.
But when I’m trying to evaluate newly added rules, I’m not getting any results, after deployment do I need to do something more?
Thanks